# Insert proper line endings in a TXT file copied from PDF

Tags: python

I wrote a program to read a PDF archive and convert it into a TXT file. The problem is it copies everything perfectly except the line endings (when these occur, the words are joined together).

This is what I have:

```
pageObj = pdf_reader.getPage(0)
text = pageObj.extractText()
file1 = open(r"C:\Users\pc\Desktop\\Pulp_Fiction.txt", "a")
file1.writelines(text)
```

And this is what it prints:
**PULP FICTIONbyQuentin Tarantino & Roger Avary**

It should print:

PULP FICTION

by

Quentin Tarantino & Roger Avary

Comment: Hola, en este sitio debes de preguntar en inglés, si no te es posible, hazlo en https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: perdon, no sabia, ahora lo edito

Comment: @ianleandro traducido :) lo hice por diversión - no lo esperes como servicio estandar :)